# How to use `templateref` from other Angular component?

Tags: angular

How to use `templateRef` from other component template file?

I have `BatmanComponent`, `SpidermanComponent` and a `JokerComponent`. Some of them have similar features, so that I decided to create a `HumanComponent`, and put all reusable HTML codes in that file, as such:

Note: the `HumanComponent` will never be used, it is just a file that consists all default template.

```html
<!-- human.component.ts -->
<ng-template #eye>
    Eyes: {{ size }}
</ng-template>
<ng-template #body>
    Body: bust {{ x[0] }}, waist {{ x[1] }}, hip {{ x[2] }} 
</ng-template>
```

May I know how to inject those template (from *human.component.ts*) and use it inside the `batman.component.ts`, etc...?

I know I can do it as such: (only **if** the template code is being copy-paste inside the *batman, spiderman, and joker* HTML files)

```html
<!-- batman.component.ts -->
<ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="eye; context: contextObj"></ng-container>

<ng-template #eye> ... </ng-template> <!-- need to copy/paste here, and use it locally -->
```

May I know how can I **export** `templateRef` to other files, and re-use them? I don't want to copy and paste similar codes across those files, I hope I can have a default template file, and just export those codes to whoever want it. Is it possible?

---

**Update:**

After reading the comments, I decided to use the **reusable component** rather than this "techniques"... Probably, the Angular team is trying hard to optimize the reusable component approach (as @artyom, @rafael, @ibenjelloun suggested), then probably just follow their path will be wiser... Haha...

Anyway, thanks.

Comment: just create a reusable component

Comment: I try to avoid reusable component, my project is floated with many components. I plan to use **reusable template approaches** (not sure if it exists) for lightweight codes. Haha... For more complex code, I did apply the reusable component approach...

Comment: When scant attempts to keep things *lightweight* or *faster* increase complexity, reconsider.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you create a `TemplatesService`, you can register your templates in it and use them in other components :

```ts
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class TemplatesService {
  templates = {};
  add(name: string, ref) {
    this.templates[name] = ref; 
  }
  get(name: string) {
    return this.templates[name];
  }
}
```

You can then add your templates to the service from a root component :

```html
{{ _templatesService.add('template1', template1) }}
{{ _templatesService.add('template2', template2) }}

<ng-template #template1 let-name="name">
  ****** Template 1 {{name}} ******
</ng-template>

<ng-template #template2 let-name="name">
  ----- Template 2 {{name}} ------
</ng-template>
```

And use them in another component :

```html
<ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="_templatesService.get('template1'); 
 context: {name: 'From Hello Component'}"></ng-container>
```

[Here is a stackblitz demo.](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackoverflow-53068272)

Comment: does this method has performance impact compare to if I (1) apply "reuse" component method, *or* (2) copy-paste all the templates into all HTML and use it locally? Is this a Angular team suggested approach? [just curios...]

Comment: I can't see a case I would use this hack on it. For your issue I would create a component, that's what its for and optimized for. Using templates would be a good idea if you want to have component containing a changing template, the component would take as input the template.