# Access template reference from a service

Tags: angular, ng-zorro-antd

I'd like to use a template reference in a service. E.g.:

```
// A component template that I want to use. Can be located anywhere.
<ng-template #announcement_tpl let-data="data">
  <div>{{data.title}}</div>
  <div>{{data.message}}</div>
</ng-template>


// Called from a callback in an injectable Service, outside the component class. 
this.notification_service.template(announcement_tpl)
```

I just implemented [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53071867/3683643). It works, but I'm not sure if this is a good practice. Note that `this.notification_service.template` is not called from a component, but from within a callback in a service, and so the template cannot simply be passed to this method. I think the ideal solution would be to import the component and get the template off of the component (somehow), unless of course there is a better way of doing it.

Comment: It sure isn't such a good practice. What exactly is the use case though? Why do you want to do that in the first place?

Comment: @SiddAjmera The `notification_service` above is actually a [UI library](https://ng.ant.design/components/notification/en#components-notification-demo-template) method to show a notification, and in order to get custom behavior, a template. So I'd like to be able to pass a custom template into the method call.